# How to extract a subset from a text file and store it in a separate file?

Tags: python, text-mining

I am currently trying to extract information from a text file using Python. I want to extract a subset from the file and store it in a separate file from everywhere it occurs in the text file. To give you an idea of what my file looks like, here is a sample:

```
C","datatype":"double","value":25.71,"measurement":"Temperature","timestamp":1573039331258250},
{"unit":"%RH","datatype":"double","value":66.09,"measurement":"Humidity","timestamp":1573039331258250}]
```

Here, I want to extract `"value"` and the corresponding number beside it. I have tried various techniques but have been unsuccessful. I tried to iterate through the file and stop at where I have `"value"` but that did not work.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
with open("DOTemp.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if "value" in part:
                print(part)
```

Comment: The file sample seems to be missing an opening `{`. It looks more or less like `.json` data, which you can easily load with the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to return the value marked by the "value" key:

```
with open("DOTemp.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        line = line.replace('"', '')
        for part in line.split(','):
            if "value" in part:
                print(part.split(':')[1])
```

Note that by default `str.split()` splits on whitespace. In the last line, if we printed element zero of the list it would just be "value". If you wish to use this as an int or float, simply cast it as such and return it.

Answer (score 1):

First split using , (comma) as the delimiter, then split the corresponding strings using : as the delimiter.
if required trim leading and trailing "" then compare with value

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work for you:

```
file1 = open("untitled.txt","r")
data = file1.readlines()

#Convert to a single string
val = ""
for d in data:
    val = val + d

#split string at comma
comma_splitted = val.split(',')

#find the required float
for element in comma_splitted:
    if 'value' in element:
        out = element.split('"value":')[1]
        print(float(out))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your input file is a json string(list of dictionaries) (looking at the file sample). If that's the case, perhaps you can try this.

```
import json

#Assuming each record is a dictionary
with open("DOTemp.txt") as openfile:
    lines = openfile.readlines()
    records = json.loads(lines)
    out_lines = list(map(lambda d: d.get('value'), records))
    with open('DOTemp_out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write("\n".join(out_lines))
```